# How to debug Gitlab LDAP authentication?

Tags: ldap, gitlab

I am trying to configure LDAP authentication with gitlab. My configuration is someting like:

```
ldap:
    enabled: true
    host: 'ldap.example.com'
    base: 'ou=People,o=example.com'
    port: 636
    uid: 'uid'
    method: 'ssl' # "ssl" or "plain"
    bind_dn: 'cn=gitlab,ou=Apps,o=example.com'
    password: 'password'
    allow_username_or_email_login: true
```

I tested it with the following :

```
ldapsearch  -b "ou=People,o=example.com" -s sub -D "cn=gitlab,ou=Apps,o=example.com" -H ldaps://ldap.example.com:636 -w "password" -x "(uid=myname@example.com)"
```

The line above works, but when I try to log in using LDAP, I always got "invalid credentials".

How can I troubleshoot this and narrow down the root cause f this problem?

Edit 26/09:

Here are some things I found on production.log:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-23 17:42:58 -0300
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered devise/sessions/_new_ldap.html.haml (1.7ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/_new_base.html.haml (1.8ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/_oauth_providers.html.haml (0.0ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/devise (4.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_head.html.haml (1.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_flash.html.haml (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 6.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started POST "/users/auth/ldap/callback" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-23 17:43:00 -0300
Processing by OmniauthCallbacksController#failure as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"â", "authenticity_token"=>"AwqZsVHRqOeZr+GLWWeGM7MyOAdk7cFl8/rZgbVRU+8=", "username"=>"name@example.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}
Redirected to http://example.com/users/sign_in
Completed 302 Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-23 17:43:00 -0300
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendered devise/sessions/_new_base.html.haml (2.8ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/_oauth_providers.html.haml (0.1ms)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.haml within layouts/devise (3.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_head.html.haml (1.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_flash.html.haml (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 9ms (Views: 6.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-23 18:50:08 -0300
Processing by DashboardController#show as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
```

Edit: I finally got the answer: a configuration on devise was stripping everyting after the "@". I can't recall the exact name, but I can post as soon as I got access to the machine. I discovered this by adding logs to the ldap oauth login.

Comment: Start by providing the server's access log. This log contains a record of each operation request and the result, and the details of the BIND, except for the password.

Comment: The only log I found was from nginx, gitlab_access.log. There aren't so many useful info in there (some request/response, with no detail of the bind)

Comment: Which LDAP server does the client use?

Comment: Probably an OpenLDAP, but I am not sure.

Comment: Does your user have an email address in ldap? It is required for gitlab.

Comment: Here are my working settings for Active Directory and gitlab 6.2 with puppet https://gist.github.com/spuder/7092511

Comment: @toobulkeh Yes, see my edit for details.

Answer (score 9):

The [OP kidbomb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/931861/kidbomb) [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18984198/6309):

> A configuration on devise was **stripping everything after the "`@`"**.
>   I discovered this by adding logs to the ldap oauth login.

---

Check if the LDAP server is also accessible through `ldap` (not `ldaps://`)

```
ldapsearch  -b "ou=People,o=example.com" -s sub -D "cn=gitlab,ou=Apps,o=example.com" -H ldap://ldap.example.com:389 -w "password" -x "(uid=myname@example.com)"
```

If yes, try and modify the `gitlab.yml` setting file `ldap.method` from 'ssl' to "`plain`".

The goal is to validate if the certificate used for contacting the ldap server is the issue here or not.

If you can contact the server through ldap:// (no certificate), that gives you at least a workaround.

If not (you have to go through `ldaps://`), you need to study more in detail the certificate associated to the LDAP server.

```
openssl s_client -connect ldap.example.com:636  2>/dev/null < /dev/null
```

(I am not using `-CAFile` or `-CAPath` here, assuming the CA are at their default place mentioned in `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`)

If you get at the end of the output of that command the message:

```
error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
```

That means you need to get the certificate from the issuer.
See "[How To Verify SSL Certificate From A Shell Prompt](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/test-ssl-certificates-diagnosis-ssl-certificate/)".

Answer (score 3):

I see you found the solution for your scenario, but I thought I'd include some additional troubleshooting steps for others who run into authentication issues with GitLab & LDAP.

- Run GitLab's LDAP rake check to localize the problem. `https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/administration/raketasks/ldap.html#check`. There's also a more comprehensive one that's listed in the GitLab install document you're using.
- If using SELinux, set it to permissive mode.
- If using Apache with GitLab: Install LDAP - Apache Directory Studio
  and try to establish a connection. If you can't then something is
  probably wrong in your config.yml file. I'd start by looking at the
  base.
- Run tcpdump and import the .pcap file into WireShark for inspection.
- Review logs on your LDAP server and your GitLab server

Answer (score 2):

We had gitlabs configured with LDAP credentials, but whenever someone logged in, we were getting "500 Internal Server Error" messages. The issue seemed to go away however when we formatted /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb correctly. It seems there are different ways to format the ldap variables, depending on what version of gitlabs you use: [7.3.2.omnibus](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/7.3.2.omnibus/README.md) and [master](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md).